# ownCloud sync client - tray icon missing

Tags: system-tray, owncloud-client

I got two ownCloud updates today: it's now sitting at `Version 2.2.0%nil (build 1605)`.

With the first one this morning, the tray icon failed to show up. I just updated now, thinking this new update would fix the problem, but it's still missing.

I get the client interface:

[image: client window screenshot]

But I would really like the "tray icon" back! I've taken a quick look at the [ownCloud forums](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewforum.php?f=14), but I failed to find anything related to this there.

Is it just me? I'm on a fairly vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (with Unity).

--

**Update** - it turns out that it is a known issue: "[Systray icon broken on Ubuntu 14.04 ater update to 2.2.0 #4828](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/4828)", so just need to await a fix.

Comment: So for the moment -- and as this is taking a while to fix -- I'm putting the client window (as in the screenshot above) in its own workspace: keeps it from being a distraction, but readily available if I want to check on something. Probably LTS upgrade will come before this gets fixed at this rate....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Github issue tracker, this bug [has now been squashed](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/4828#issuecomment-222102159). Updates should soon be showing up via package management.

As noted in [one of the comments](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/4828#issuecomment-222141538), if you have run the OwnCloud client before, but are affected by this bug on 14.04, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get remove owncloud-client-l10n owncloud-client libowncloudsync0 && sudo apt-get install owncloud-client-l10n owncloud-client libowncloudsync0
```

That fixed it for me (after logout/in).

Answer (score 0):

As explain in the issue: "[Systray icon broken on Ubuntu 14.04 ater update to 2.2.0 #4828](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/659)", there is a conflic between Qt version and Owncloud. I try to remove and reinstall, but I get a dependency error message and owncloud can't be re-install on my Ubuntu 14.04.

So if your owncloud client works, with or without the system tray icone, don't remove it.

Cedric.